# Read and write massive text files in scala

Tags: scala

How should I read and write massive text files in scala, avoiding crashes due huge memory requirements?

**example case**

input file has 3 million strings, and the following code obviously crashes

```scala
// The first line of the file contains input data type and total number of lines

  val src = Source.fromFile("in.txt").getLines
  val header = src.next.split(" ").toVector
  val lines = (if (header(0) == "i") src.map(_.toInt) else src).toArray

  process(lines) // no lines are removed during processing

  val writer = new PrintWriter("out.txt", "UTF-8")
  try writer.print(lines.mkString("\n"))
  finally writer.close
```

How should I

- split data into chunks (and how to decide individual chunk size?)
- process chunks
- merge chunks
- write an output file

Comment: If you can chunk the data, is there some reason you can't process it line by line?  In other words, leave `src` as in `Iterator` (don't turn it into an `Array`), then process and write each line until the iterator is empty and close the out-file.

Comment: I need to process all lines at once, and few million strings and ints should fit completely to the memory. My first idea was to do something like this: https://bpaste.net/show/4d5eaba7d689

Comment: @warbaque I had to run suddenly so I temporarily took down my answer. I will try to finish it tomorrow if someone doesn't answer you by then.

Comment: I actually fixed crashing but just allocating more memory to JVM (stupid me). I need to edit question a bit, but the question still stands. I also noticed that reading file takes 1.5 seconds, processing takes 0.6 seconds,  and writing takes 2.8 seconds. It this case I can't start writing before all lines are processed, but processing and reading could be done atleast partially in parallel.

Comment: @warbaque I have updated my answer, please let me know if it addresses your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Direct Answers to Your Questions

- chunk size - Chunk size is a function of speed/space. The larger the chuck the more quickly (in general) you can process the data, but the memory usage will be directly proportional to chuck size.
- process chucks - Since you *can't hold all the data in memory, you need to filter the data you don't need and only keep the result you do need. This is rather abstract since it depends very directly on your use case. For instance if you wanted to count the number of times the character 'a' occurred in a text file, you would look through each chunk for the letter 'a', increment an integer, and discard the chunk and continue.
- merge chunks - Typically you can just apply the result from the previous computation to the next computation (i.e. like a fold). So you don't really need to *merge* chunks. Are you talking about concurrently doing this in a distributed manner (it sounds like you might be)?
- write an output file - Again, you will want to do this in a stream/incremental manner. If you need to produce a large output corpus, then flush to output as soon as you have a partial result. The disadvantage to this is that if an error occurs you have a partially built output file you need to clean up.

### A Simple Solution

In order to do this you need to stream process the data. This can be done in a variety of ways. Using a library that specializes in stream processing is a *very* good way to go. `scalaz-stream` is a good example of such a library.

Their [github](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) page has example code on how to do exactly what you are asking. Read in a large (possibly infinite) file, perform some transformation upon the data, all with constant memory usage.

This is a copy of the example from their README.md

```
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

val converter: Task[Unit] =
  io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
    .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.txt"))
    .run

// at the end of the universe...
val u: Unit = converter.run
```

You can of course construct this sort of stream processing from just the standard library. In that case you would probably want to either process it in terms of lines or in terms of bytes (the former being easier the latter being safer since there is no guarantee that there will be ANY linebreaks even in very large files). Personally I would strongly recommend `scalaz-stream`.

### A Pure Scala Solution

A pure scala solution would be to use something like `scala.io.Source`. For instance, this will program will count the number of times the character 'a' occurs in the file, and it will do it in constant memory.

Note, you are using `Source` in your example, but you are calling converting it into an in memory data structure (specifically an `Array` which is *not* a streaming construct).

```
import scala.io.Source

object Streaming extends App {

  args.headOption.foreach{(file: String) =>
    println(
      s"Number of 'a' is: ${Source.fromFile(file).count(_ == 'a')}"
    )
  }
}
```

### A Java/Scala Solution

Now `Source` is pretty easy to work with, but it is really only designed for character data. If you need something more robust, perhaps that handles arbitrary binary data, then you will want to use the Java standard library.

Note, there are other primitives you might use to do this in the standard library, these are just the ones I chose. They use the java.nio package which I have read is more performant (I haven't done any benchmarking myself).

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.file.FileSystems
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

object Streaming extends App {


  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def countStuff(
    buffer: ByteBuffer,
    byteChannel: ReadableByteChannel,
    count: BigInt
  ): BigInt = {
    val newCount = byteChannel.read(buffer)
    if (newCount == -1) {
      println("Done reading")
      count
    } else {
      println(s"Read ${newCount + count} bytes!")
      buffer.clear()
      countStuff(buffer, byteChannel, count + newCount)
    }
  }

  args.headOption.foreach{(file: String) =>
    val byteChannel =
      Files.newByteChannel(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(file))
    countStuff(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024), byteChannel, 0)
    byteChannel.close()
  }
}
```

This counts the number of bytes it has read, prints out the current count, and does so in constant memory. Obviously this is a pretty boring use, but you can hopefully see how you might change it to your needs.

### Why Streaming At All

You asked why you can't just operate on all of this in memory. You of course *can* do that, depending on your available memory (adjustable with the JVM options) and the size of your input. The answer here *assumes* that you need to operate on data that is arbitrarily large. If you don't need to do that, the processing the entire corpus into memory is often the easier solution.

Again, the Scala/Java standard library examples are only here because you said you *can't* use something like `scalaz-stream` which is what I would normally do in this case.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have access to scalaz or akka at this point.

Comment: Okay. I am updating with another solution then

Comment: Why can't I hold all the data in the memory? Shouldn't few million ints or strings fit memory just nicely? I need to load all lines before I can complete processing (I need to do sort all lines along other stuff)

Comment: @warbaque you can load all the data into memory, if you have enough memory for the data. Since your program was crashing on the first line, you didn't have enough.